# Conditional matching in Regex

Tags: regex

Consider a phrase:
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

I want to write a regex of the form:

```
if phrase doesn't contain `cat` then
  does phrase contain dog?
else
  no match
end
```

I think it should be

```
(?(cat)|dog)
```

But this doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The logic from your if-else pseudo code actually isn't that clear.

Comment: So, if  `^(?!.*cat).*dog.*` does not work for you, you might probably want something like `(?<!cat.*)dog(?!.*cat)`